# Configuring 1:N relationship delete cascade fails in Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm having troubles getting this bit of a Code First model to produce a database.

Here are the two models in question:

```
public class Workflow : BaseEntity, IBaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PublishedOn { get; set; }

    public int Revision { get; set; } = 0;
    public Guid PermanentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WorkflowStage> WorkflowStages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkflowDataFactor> WorkflowDataFactors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkflowInstance> WorkflowInstances { get; set; }

}
```

And here's the 2nd model:

```
public class WorkflowStage : BaseEntity, IBaseEntity
{

    public int WorkflowId { get; set; }
    public virtual Workflow Workflow { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int Revision { get; set; } = 0;
    public Guid PermanentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WorkflowStageStep> WorkflowStageSteps { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkflowStageInstance> WorkflowStageInstances { get; set; }


}
```

`BaseEntity` provides all my other entities with an `Id` property, which is the primary key.

After getting this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.WorkflowStage_dbo.Workflow_WorkflowId' on table
>   'WorkflowStage' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
>   errors.

I implemented this in my context class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Workflow>().HasMany(x => x.WorkflowStages).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

If I understand correctly, this is saying if a `WorkflowStage` gets deleted, the associated `Workflow` shouldn't be deleted.

Isn't it what EF6 is looking for according to the error at the top ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see cycles or multiple cascade paths in the shown model (does `BaseEntity` contain navigation property/FK like `User` or something?) Anyway, the fluent config is incorrect - `.WithRequired()` should be `WithRequired(x => x.Workflow)`

Comment: Please show the model with all involved relationships. This probably doesn't merely depend on the one full association we can see here.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in your context class for:

`modelBuilder.Entity<Workflow>()
            .HasOptional<WorkflowStages>(s => s.WorkflowStages)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`

Answer (score 0):

"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.WorkflowStage_dbo.Workflow_WorkflowId' on table 'WorkflowStage' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths..."

What the could mean is that you have multiple tables that lead to another table and each of them has the OnCascade setting. You can't do this in SQL Server.

Table1 ==> Table2 with Cascade
Table3 ==> Table2 with Cascade <<-- no no no!!

So how many tables interact with WorkFlowStage? Are there multiple tables that could cascade to it? Would it be possible to wind up with orphan records by removing the cascade from one table or the other? For instance if you remove the cascade delete from WorkFlow then could you wind up with WorkFlowStage that doesn't belong to anything? Perhaps removing the cascade from the other table involved would be more appropriate.
In some cases I have created Triggers for AFTER DELETE on a table which can be used to clean up child records without the constraint. 
HTH,
Mike